# PHP to display rows from MySQL query based on id and group by datewise

Tags: php, mysql

The select query outputs values for each basestation_id on a particular date wise sorted by the avg. I would like to display the table in php from Mysql query result as shown below.

```
basestation_id  12-Jun-18   13-Jun-18   14-Jun-18   15-Jun-18   16-Jun-18
    5            value1      value2     value3      value4      value5
    3            value1      value2     value3      value4      value5
    4            value1      value2     value3      value4      value5
    1            value1      value2     value3      value4      value5
    2            value1      value2     value3      value4      value5
```

But the code display results as

```
date            12-Jun-18   12-Jun-18   12-Jun-18   12-Jun-18   13-Jun-18 ...    
basetstaion_id  5             3          4            1           2      ...
values          value1      value1      value1      value1     value2   ...
```

PHP:-

```
<?
foreach($result as $key => $row) {
   foreach($row as $field => $value) {
       $recNew[$field][] = $value;
   }
}
//This creates a new array composed/transposed with the field names as keys 
//and the "rowed" values as sub-arrays.

echo "<table>\n";

foreach ($recNew as $key => $values) // For every field name (basestation_id, 
// , dates, values)
{
  echo "<tr>\n"; // start the row
  echo "\t<td>" . $key . "</td>\n" ; // create a table cell with the field 
name
    foreach ($values as $cell) // for every sub-array iterate through all 
values
    {
       echo "\t<td>" . $cell . "</td>\n"; // write cells next to each other
    }
echo "</tr>\n"; // end row

}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Sample Data:-

```
delivery_date   col_head    basestation_id  receptions  daily_avg_stats
16-Jun-18      Sat 16 Jun   152              0           under_avg
16-Jun-18      Sat 16 Jun   13               0           under_avg
16-Jun-18      Sat 16 Jun   140              0           under_avg
16-Jun-18      Sat 16 Jun   12               1093        under_avg
16-Jun-18      Sat 16 Jun   9                0           under_avg
16-Jun-18      Sat 16 Jun   1                50          under_avg
16-Jun-18      Sat 16 Jun   5                250         under_avg
.   .   .      .                                         
15-Jun-18      Fri 15 Jun   152              0           under_avg
15-Jun-18      Fri 15 Jun   13               0           under_avg
15-Jun-18      Fri 15 Jun   140              0           under_avg
15-Jun-18      Fri 15 Jun   12               1734        under_avg
15-Jun-18      Fri 15 Jun   9                0           under_avg
15-Jun-18      Fri 15 Jun   1                0           under_avg
```

SQL Query to display the results with "under avg" values listed first:-

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        DATE(r.ad_date) AS delivery_date,
            DATE_FORMAT(r.ad_date, '%a %d %b') AS col_head,
            r.basestation_id,
            r.receptions,
            (CASE
                WHEN r.receptions > FLOOR(avg.monthly_receptions_avg * 1.3) THEN 'over_avg'
                WHEN r.receptions < FLOOR(avg.monthly_receptions_avg * 0.7) THEN 'under_avg'
            END) AS daily_avg_stats
    FROM
        receptions r
    JOIN receptions_avg avg ON r.basestation_id = avg.basestation_id
    WHERE
        r.ad_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
            AND avg.ad_date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ORDER BY basestation_id , delivery_date) abc
ORDER BY delivery_date DESC , FIELD(abc.daily_avg_stats, 'under_avg') DESC
```

Comment: remove `\n` and `\t` you're creating a table you don't need those.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data

Comment: And please post you query and provide an example of your table structure.

Comment: updated.. Thanks

Comment: Any updates @Joseph_J

Comment: anyone would like to answer this??

Comment: Ive been away for awhile, Im actually looking at it right now.  Give me a bit.

Comment: Could you do a `print_r($result)` and post a chunck of that result in your post.

Comment: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 5 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 6300 [type] => 0 )

Comment: What you posted is the result that the query object returned.  I actually want to see your data in the array form.  `print_r($result)` should print an array with your rows of data.  Paste a few elements of that data in as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
<?
foreach($result as $key => $row) {
   foreach($row as $field => $value) {
       $recNew[$field][] = $value;
   }
}
//This creates a new array composed/transposed with the field names as keys 
//and the "rowed" values as sub-arrays.

echo "<table>";

foreach ($recNew as $key => $values) // For every field name (basestation_id, 
// , dates, values)
{
  echo "<tr>"; // start the row
  echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>" ; // create a table cell with the field 
name
    foreach ($values as $cell) // for every sub-array iterate through all 
values
    {
       echo "<td>" . $cell . "</td>"; // write cells next to each other
    }
echo "</tr>"; // end row

}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: As suggested by @hungrykoala, tried it already but it did not helped.. Results are still displayed in similar manner.